# Accessing jQuery ajax error in Promise.all catch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, es6-promise

I am running several ajax requests using jQuery in a Promise.all:

```
const firstFetchPromise = $.ajax({ url: '/some/url' });
const secondFetchPromise = $.ajax({ url: '/another/url' });

Promise.all([ firstFetchPromise, secondFetchPromise ])
  .then(results => storeResults(results))
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // e is a promise, how to get the ajax error?
  });
```

To test the error handling I shutdown the server that the ajax requests are getting their data from and the browser logs an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE with the URL.

The catch statement logs something that looks like a promise:

```
abort:ƒ (a),
always:ƒ (),
complete:ƒ (),
done:ƒ (),
error:ƒ (),
fail:ƒ (),
getAllResponseHeaders:ƒ (),
getResponseHeader:ƒ (a),
overrideMimeType:ƒ (a),
pipe:ƒ (),
progress:ƒ (),
promise:ƒ (a),
readyState:0,
responseText:"",
setRequestHeader:ƒ (a,b),
state:ƒ (),
status:0,
statusCode:ƒ (a),
statusText:"error",
success:ƒ (),
then:ƒ (),
```

How do I get the ajax error that's in the promise so I can display a readable error message in the web page?

Comment: `e is a promise` - it shouldn't be - that console log you've shown doesn't look anything like a promise (getResponseHeader, getAllResponseHeaders, setRequestHeader, overrideMimeType all look like XHR methods)

Comment: That might very well be the case, I'm new to promises, more used to callbacks. I've updated the question with the complete object. I was expecting that there would be some network related error message. The object as keys like promise, then, fail etc so I figured it was a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

In this case, that is `$.ajax`'s [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

You can get the error like this:

```
Promise.all([ firstFetchPromise, secondFetchPromise ])
  .then(results => storeResults(results))
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e.responseText); // Server response

    e.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(e === jqXHR);  // true
      console.log(textStatus);   // 'error'
      console.log(errorThrown);  // 'HTTP/2.0 404'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Is there no way to get information about the error? I would have thought that browsers would have more than just "error".

Comment: You can get the server response in `e.responseText`.